# i want to call click_through_rate function after group by but using aggregate function i am not able to resolve this

Tags: python, pandas

function to calculate click-though_rate

```
#function to calculate click-though_rate 
def click_through_rate(cust_engage_trans):    
n = len(pd.unique(cust_engage_trans['hash_email']))
filtr = cust_engage_trans[(cust_engage_trans.open_rate == 1) & (cust_engage_trans.click_rate == 1)]
n2 = len(pd.unique(filtr['hash_email']))
CTR = (n2/n)*100
return (CTR)
CTR_ByGroup=cust_engage_trans.groupby(by=['Treatment_Group']).apply(click_through_rate).to_frame('CTR_Group')
print(CTR_ByGroup)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't receive an error with this.  I have interpreted your code as the following (next time, perhaps you could ask the question with it laid out as code rather than text with lines of code not split up to make it easier for others to look at), let me know if this is not correct.

```
#function to calculate click-though_rate

def click_through_rate(cust_engage_trans):

    n = len(pd.unique(cust_engage_trans['hash_email']))

    filtr = cust_engage_trans[(cust_engage_trans.open_rate == 1) & (cust_engage_trans.click_rate == 1)]

    n2 = len(pd.unique(filtr['hash_email']))
    
    CTR = (n2/n)*100
    
    return (CTR)

# Mock Data
cust_engage_trans = pd.DataFrame(data={"hash_email": ["alpha", "beta", "gamma", "alpha", "beta", "gamma"],
                                       "open_rate": [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                                       "click_rate": [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                                       "Treatment_Group": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two", "two"]})

CTR_ByGroup=cust_engage_trans.groupby(by=['Treatment_Group']).apply(click_through_rate).to_frame('CTR_Group')
print(CTR_ByGroup)

#Out:
#                 CTR_Group
#Treatment_Group           
#one              33.333333
#two              66.666667
```

One problem might be that column data types are incompatible with the calculations (e.g. your open or click rates might be as strings but looking for integer `1`).  Would you also be able to provide some sample data for your initial dataframe (`cust_engage_trans`) so others can try to recreate the problem?